# Does it make sense to conduct cluster analysis with single variables as well as a variables derived from multiple items?

Tags: clustering

As part of my research I wonder whether it would be OK to conduct a cluster analysis with variables derived from a multiple item construct, as well as single variables.

The objective is to segment consumers based on their evaluations of food attributes, e.g. the variable "naturalness" is based upon a 3 questions-construct ("no additives", "no artificial ingredients", "only natural ingredients"), whereas the variable "gluten-free" is based on a single question. All questions are scaled the same way (7-point from "very unimportant" to "very important").

Despite this difference, can I conduct a cluster analysis with the variables "naturalness" and "gluten-free" (among others)?

Comment: Welcome to CV! I think you ought to clarify whether your analysis is going to include both "naturalness" itself, as well as the individual items that it was constructed from, or just "naturalness"? (But I hope any answers to this question address the point of whether this is acceptable anyway.)

Comment: I agree with Silverfish, clarification is needed. When you write that '"naturalness" is based upon a 3-item scale," does this mean that 3 individual question items go into the construct "naturalness" or does it mean that "naturalness" is scaled with a single 3-point response set, e.g., agree, neutral, disagree? Similarly for "gluten-free" where the question is whether it's scaled the same as "naturalness" but based on a single question item.

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies and pointing out my unclear description. Let me clarify the issue: "Naturalness" is based on 3 questions ("no additives", "no artificial ingredients", "only natural ingredients"), whereas "gluten-free" is just based on a single question. All questions are scaled the same way (7-point from "very unimportant" to "very important"). I hope this makes my question clearer. I will edit my above question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details might depend on the method of cluster analysis you're using, but in general, yes, I think it's fine. Just be sure to put your variables on a common scale (e.g., divide each by its standard deviation) if the method requires that.

This said, it seems to me more straightforward and sensible to use the original items (e.g., "no additives") for your cluster analysis, rather than composite items. Combining items into composites might be throwing away information that could be useful for clustering.

Comment: Just to make sure, I understand you right: Since I have measured all variables on the same 7-point scale, there is no further need to e.g. divide each by its standard deviation - is that right? I haven´t decided yet on the cluster method. My sample is 300 and I have found papers suggesting that this size suggests k-means. I might run a hierarchical clustering beforehand to determine the number of clusters. If I use the original items of "naturalness" wouldn´t that overrepresent that variable? These 3 original items are also correlated, which might argue against their use

Comment: "Since I have measured all variables on the same 7-point scale, there is no further need to e.g. divide each by its standard deviation - is that right?" — Not really. It may still be worth dividing by the standard deviation so that items for which subjects use a narrow subsection of the scale (e.g., because of a ceiling effect) are not weighted as more important than other items.

Comment: "If I use the original items of 'naturalness' wouldn't that overrepresent that variable?" — In a sense, yes, but this may be appropriate considering that you actually have more items for it. It's up to you. "These 3 original items are also correlated, which might argue against their use." — I think most clustering methods are designed with dependencies between variables in mind.